# Delphi Win32_EventLog Class

Tags: delphi

Trying to convert so I can specify which log to backup
Getting invalid query with line
How do I correctly specify the param to the query

```
FWbemObjectSet:= FWMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT * FROM Win32_NTEventlogFile Where        LogFileName=' + Log +' ','WQL',wbemFlagForwardOnly);
```

Correct syntax that works is this

```
FWbemObjectSet:= FWMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT * FROM Win32_NTEventlogFile Where LogFileName="Application"','WQL',wbemFlagForwardOnly);
```

Procedure

```
procedure EventLog(Log : string);
const
wbemFlagForwardOnly = $00000020;
var
FSWbemLocator : OLEVariant;
FWMIService   : OLEVariant;
FWbemObjectSet: OLEVariant;
FWbemObject   : OLEVariant;
oEnum         : IEnumvariant;
iValue        : LongWord;
begin
  FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  FWMIService   := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer('localhost', 'root\CIMV2', '', '');
  FWbemObjectSet:= FWMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT * FROM Win32_NTEventlogFile Where        LogFileName=' + Log +' ','WQL',wbemFlagForwardOnly);
  oEnum         := IUnknown(FWbemObjectSet._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  if oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, iValue) = 0 then
  begin
    FWbemObject.BackupEventLog(SaveDirectory + Computer + Log + '.evt');
    FWbemObject:=Unassigned;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Did you just answer the question asked in the first two lines with the lines below: `Correct syntax that works is this`?  That's not how SO works.  You ask the question (just the question) and then answer it in the answer box below.

Comment: If my assumption is wrong, then I'm confused and I suggest you rephrase the question.

Comment: No you are good I forgot to close the select properly now that I have done that it's working

Comment: Did you see: http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2011/11/16/wmi-tasks-using-delphi-services/

Comment: I did  that where I stumbled across the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind figured it out

```
FWbemObjectSet:= FWMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT * FROM Win32_NTEventlogFile Where LogFileName="' + Log +'"','WQL',wbemFlagForwardOnly);
```

Comment: Injecting text into a query like that is **bad** practice, because it allows sql-injection exploits. You should use parameters instead. (Not sure if WMI allows parameters though).

Comment: this is going to be used by our tech's to export the event logs on our server along with log files, I know injecting isn't the best idea but I am not too worried about it for this project